Is there a way to search and compare through 2 different columns of strings of a csv file?
I'm making a taxonomic cladogram using networkx for a university project. I'm trying to connect the taxonomic name with its parent name, going from each species name, up to each family name until the base of the cladogram. For this I'm comparing the name in one column with the names in the other column and making an edge between the dots generated, however I'm not able to search through the columns the way I want to and the error is too extensive to get the solution in a quick google search, if anybody knows a way to do this please let me know.
this is the code I'm trying
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#df = pd.read_csv("E:/Escritorio/tp mat 3/pbdb_data.csv") #direccion labo
df = pd.read_csv("D:/unsam/mat 3/TP 1/pbdb_data.csv") #direccion pc
df = df.drop(["orig_no","taxon_no","record_type","flags","difference","accepted_no","parent_no","immpar_no","immpar_name","container_no","reference_no","is_extant"], axis=1)

print(df)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(df["taxon_name"])

for i in df["parent_name"]:
    for j in df["taxon_name"]:
        if df[i] == df[j]:
            x =+ 1

print (x)
nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.draw()

the csv is like this:
taxon_rank                taxon_name   accepted_rank             accepted_name      parent_name  n_occs
0    unranked clade                Dinosauria  unranked clade                Dinosauria  Dinosauriformes    1952
1    unranked clade            Megalosauridae  unranked clade            Megalosauridae       Dinosauria       2
2    unranked clade              Ornithischia  unranked clade              Ornithischia       Dinosauria     236
3    unranked clade                Genasauria  unranked clade                Genasauria     Ornithischia     208
4    unranked clade                  Cerapoda  unranked clade                  Cerapoda       Genasauria     173


I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. 'Dinosauria', for example, appears in parent_name multiple times and I guess that it occurs in taxon_name multiple times as well. so if we assume that it occurs only two times in each column, then x will be 4. Is that what you are looking for?

yeah, sorry, i didnt clarify but the x is just a placeholder, to see if i could compare the columns, in the end what i would do is to make an edge between the taxon name with the next taxon name wich has the parent name coinciding with the previous one

So if I understand you correctly, you want to add a new column that holds a chain from the top parent name to the current taxon_name, right? if so, is it assured the taxon_name can have only one parent name? if not, how can you tell which parent_name is the right for the current taxon_name?

im trying to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167616/cladogram-tree-of-life-cladistics-taxonomy-in-js-or-canvas (i just want a graph made with networkx)  each taxon name has only one parent name, but the parent name may be connected to multiple other taxa, in the graph im only using the taxon name to make the nodes, and i know that the parent names are all in a certain row of the column taxon name, except for dinosauriformes, im tryng to make a network using that information (btw, the csv is much longer, i just put these few rows as an example)

as an example that you can imagine with these rows is i would have dinosauria as the base node for the graph, then it connects to Megalosauridae and Ornithischia in different branches, then genasauria would be a branch of ornitischia and cerapoda a branch of genasauria

this is a better example of what im trying to achieve: http://faculty.smcm.edu/wihatch/QR/POBhtml/POBprotoCnidariaScyphozoa.html

I couldn't find a tree graph like something you are looking for on networkx
However you can try:
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df[["parent_name", "taxon_name"]].drop_duplicates(), 'parent_name', 'taxon_name', create_using=nx.Graph())
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True)


thanks, this worked very well, i just need to adjust the graphic aspect of it
